# NiFi. Добавление пустой колонки id в csv

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

Только осваиваю NiFi. Задача состоит в том, чтобы взять csv-файл из облака, добавить пустую колонку id и залить полученные данные в PostgreSQL. Вылазит ошибка, что сделал не так?

[image: Параметры UpdateRecord] [image: Параметры CSVReader] [image: Схема в CSVReader] [image: Параметры CSVRecordSetWriter] [image: Схема в CSVRecordSetWriter] [image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 1):

Используйте процессор UpdateRecord. Попробуйте добавить новое поле  /id c пустым значением